# Could I use use EfCore as ORM for WPF Project

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, orm, ef-core-2.0

I Want to create a project  with WPF  and i need an ORM to use SQL
database.
In my project performance is very important so i decide to use 
EfCore, but all samples and tutorials about Efcore use asp.net ?!,
I couldn't find any sample to use Efcore with WinForm or WPF.
Could I use EfCore for WPF ?

Comment: EF Core supports Full Framework, so yes, you can use it with WPF. You can start from the official documentation - [Compare EF Core & EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) and [Getting Started with EF Core on .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/)

Comment: And EF Core can use INotifyPropertyChanged, etc for change tracking, which you're probably using anyway in WPF. https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/11/16/notification-entities-in-ef-core-1-1/

Comment: Thanks David,but as i checked ,if i want to use EfCore i should use .NetCore template projects and it  doesn't have any template for wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
You should update Vs 2017 to install NetStandard 2 then you could install
EfCore .